# Is it possible to put an ArrayList<Location> and ArrayList<Long> in a bundle?

Tags: android

I have an `ArrayList<Location>` and `ArrayList<Long>` that i want to pass it to a new Activity which will use these to write to a GPX file. The GPX file writing is not the problem but within the new Activity will add other information to the file so the two `ArrayList<>` will be needed to be passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to use Parcelable. You can't use bundle to pass ArrayList of data.

Comment: Thanks. Also just realised that Location implements Parcelable already.

Comment: you can pass an `ArrayList` of data using `putSerializable` too, but then you'll have to cast the value to `ArrayList<Long>` when retrieving it